# C# Default Parameters being yelled about

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, optional-parameters

I have a web app I have been tasked with trying to debug and fix. Not my code. 
The app is targeting the 4.0 Framework, which as near as I can tell, is [C# version 4.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29#Versions) as well.

The website will not compile, and is giving the following error: `Default parameter specifiers are not permitted.`

It complains in two spots, here is one of them:

`private static void setDateCell(string cellXY, object value, string format = "MM/dd/yyyy") {`

The other spot is a similar function declaration but for numbers and with a different default format.

As far as I can tell from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_4.0), v4.0 of C# was when default parameters were introduced. I've double checked the web site property pages to make sure it is targeting Framework 4.0. So I'm not sure why it is complaining about having optional parameters.

I've tried running `aspnet_regiis -i`; no joy.

Any ideas?

We were using VS2010 Express. We're currently installing VS2015 Express... to see if maybe it is an issue with 2010.

Comment: It may be because default parameters are not supported in a web service or web app. And I think overloading is also not supported, so you couldn't add two actions with the same name but differing parameters. On way to handle it is if blank or null are passed for `format` then reset it to `"MM/dd/yyyy"`

Answer (score 2):

Check the `targetFramework` attribute of the `<compilation>` node of your `Web.config`.
Maybe it's stuck to something lower than 4.0 for some reason. Another way to check/fix this is to toggle your project to 3.5, then to 4.0 again.

Comment: Hmm, It had that attribute in, but VS was complaining about it, so I took it out. This also is VS2010. We are installing VS2015 on the machine now, to see if maybe 2010 just couldn't handle the latest and greatest mess. Will try these if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Serge, who's answer turned me on to the problem. Visual Studio 2010 does not support compiling with that attribute. We installed VS2015 on the machine, and edited it there, and then we were able to target a higher Framework version, and continue on our way.